# .htaccess, rewrite 404 errors to other domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I redirect all the 404 errors to another domain?

I've found the

```
Error 404 http://example.com/error.html
```

But I need:

```
if Error 404 (.*) http://example.com/$1
```

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1
```

But it redirects all the requests, in fact if I run a .php script which generate a page with some 404 links the URL of the script becomes

```
http://example.com/script.php
```

Instead the URL should remains the same and just the 404 links should get redirected to the other domain.

Solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1 - Create `ErrorDocument` directive like this:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**2 - Then create your `404.php` like this:**

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "domain.com") // current domain
      header('Location: http://example.com' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], TRUE, 301);
?>
```

**UPDATE Using just .htaccess:**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```