# How to Redirect non existing pages 'on the fly' to different domains

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I will try to explain:
I have a domain - example.com without any other pages.
I want to be able create a redirect from non existing link, example.com/whatever to nba.com, how can I do it, without creating a example.com/whatever page? 
I want to have a website without pages, only domain, that will work for me as a redirect center, i mean - I want have 100 random links from example.com/****** that the 1st link will redirect to website1 , 2nd to website2.com and etc.

I understand that I must have a Database, with at least 1 table, with 2 rows, in 1st row - random links from example.com/*** in 2nd row - links to redirected websites. But how to make a redirect, if pages do not exist ? 
Using php or another technique ? Please help.

Comment: I don't think you need a database if you just want to redirect urls. That can be done via the `.htaccess`.

Comment: I dont understand how to achieve that...

Comment: If you show me what you've tried, maybe I can help you.

Comment: nothing bro, everything in the mind. I just have a clear one page website on my local machine in wamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need `.htaccess` for this. Find the root directory of your hosting account where the domain is (usually `public_html`) and create a `.htaccess` file with the following in it:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Now create an `index.php` file in your root directory with something like this:

```
<?php 
$websites = array( 'http://www.websiteone.com', 'http://www.websitetwo.com' );
$random_website = array_rand( $websites );
header( "Location: {$random_website}", TRUE, 301 );
?>
```

You can keep adding elements to the `$website` array variable. This example assumes your server is setup and can use `PHP` to run the code.

If you are going to configure a database to retrieve the value:

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM websites ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$website = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$random_website = $website->website;
$conn->close();
header( "Location: {$random_website}", TRUE, 301 );
?>
```

This code assumes your table in the database is called `websites` that has a field called `website` where the URL is stored.

Comment: Thanks you, its almost it what I look for! Thanks, but i will try to keep data with original link and destination link in the DB and display it on page, with cells update enable from an html page.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a database call but it makes assumptions about your server setup and also skill level in PHP/MySQL to accomplish. Good luck!

Comment: yeah, it would be hard for me.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by .htaccess and a php file:

**.htaccess:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

**404.php:**

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == "example.com") // current domain
      header('Location: http://nba.com/', TRUE, 301);
?>
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764078/5692251

Comment: ok, but if I need to make a 1000 random links with redirects ?

Comment: then you make the header out of the db info.

Comment: @SpaceSpice *"1000 random links with redirects"* what do you mean?

Comment: @LordNeo I think about that, but my skills is low, can you give an example or something please?

Comment: @SpaceSpice you need to do it by yourself, StackOverflow is for fixing what you've done, not for doing it for you. It's pretty easy to google on how to dump some data from the database and then "write it" like you need to.

Comment: im just asking for example, you can just point a link, and its not googled, I can't find it. I know how to get data/ insert data, but idk how to redirect the page that doesnt exist, how to generate a php code with redirect on page that doesnt exist.